# How can I merge an array into the child level of another array (recursively)?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

array1:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["1234"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(10) "monkey.jpg"
    }
    ["3456"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(9) "horse.jpg"

    }
  }
}
```

array2:

```
array(2) {
  ["number"]=>
  string(2) "62"
  ["company"]=>
  string(7) "animals"
}
```

I want to merge the two arrays together:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
```

This is the result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["1234"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["fileName"]=>
          string(10) "monkey.jpg"
        }
     ["3456"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["fileName"]=>
          string(9) "horse.jpg"   
     }
  }
  ["number"]=>
  string(2) "62"
  ["company"]=>
  string(7) "animals"
}
```

But the result I would actually need is this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
     ["1234"]=>
          array(1) {
         ["fileName"]=>
          string(10) "monkey.jpg"
         }
      ["3456"]=>
         array(1) {
            ["fileName"]=>
           string(9) "horse.jpg"   
         }
      ["number"]=>
      string(2) "62"
      ["company"]=>
      string(7) "animals"
  }
}
```

How could I achieve this?

---

I test `array_push` like `RaymondNijland` suggested:

```
array_push($array1[0],$array2);
```

But now the `$array1` looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["1234"]=>
     array(1) {
     ["fileName"]=>
      string(10) "monkey.jpg"
       }
    ["3456"]=>
       array(1) {
        ["fileName"]=>
        string(9) "horse.jpg"   
      }
    }
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        ["number"]=>
         string(2) "62"
         ["company"]=>
         string(7) "animals"
    }
  }
}
```

Still not the result I am looking for

Comment: "How could I achieve this?" Looks to me just as simple as `$array1[0][] = $array2` or `array_push($array1[0], $array2)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just tested your suggestion and my result is `int(3)`. Nothing more. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should provide actual PHP code not some output what looks to be `var_dump()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland My code is `$result = array_push($array1[0], $array2)`

Comment: `var_dump($array1)` after the `array_push($array1[0], $array2)` then you will see that $array1 is changed..

Comment: But provide your complete php code not just one line.. No body will be able to help you like this.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I provided your code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add to the existing array, iterate through the new array and add each element of it.

Here's the function and example usage:

```
function array_merge_recursive_custom($array1, $array2){
    $result[] = $array1;

    foreach($array2 as $key=>$value){
        $result[0][$key] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

$array1 = ['1234' => ['fileName' => 'monkey.jpg'], '3456' => ['fileName' => 'horse.jpg']];
$array2 = ['number' => '62', 'company' => 'animals'];

$result = array_merge_recursive_custom($array1, $array2);

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [1234]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(10) "monkey.jpg"
    }
    [3456]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fileName"]=>
      string(9) "horse.jpg"
    }
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "62"
    ["company"]=>
    string(7) "animals"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3 = $array1;
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
  $array3[0][$key] = $value;
}
```